# CloudWatch agent per-instance streams

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm using CloudWatch Agent (not CloudWatch Logs Agent) on a Windows instance. The configuration file amazon-cloudwatch-agent.toml includes a hard-coded instance id. If I create an AMI for an auto-scaling group, every instance launched uses that same stale instance id for the log stream. They all write to the same stream.

I'd like every instance to write to a stream with its own instance_id. Which seems like what you'd almost always want. How is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch-Agent-Configuration-File-Details.html#CloudWatch-Agent-Configuration-File-Logssection):

> log_stream_name – Optional. Specifies what to use as the log stream name in CloudWatch Logs. As part of the name, you can use {instance_id}, {hostname}, {local_hostname}, and {ip_address} as variables within the name. {hostname} retrieves the hostname from the EC2 metadata, while {local_hostname} uses the hostname from the network configuration file.
>
> If you omit this field, the default of {instance_id} is used. A log stream is created automatically if it does not already exist.

So the simplest thing to do is to not define log_stream_name at all.

It *is* wierd that the agent uses the .toml file for its config and not the json file and the toml generation is only done at install time. Maybe you can force a toml regeneration using:

```
$/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/config-translator \
  --input /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.json \
  --output /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.toml \
  --mode ec2 \
  --config /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/common-config.toml
```

You may even be able to stick this in the userdata script. agent might need a restart as well.

Comment: The problem is the JSON can take those variables, and does use {instance_id} by default. But then you have to convert the JSON into a TOML file, and that hard-codes the instance id. The actual CloudWatch Agent reads the TOML file. What I think is needed is a way to tell the instance to generate the TOML file on startup. I really wish the Agent read the JSON and interpreted it, that would make a lot more sense to me.

Comment: how are you starting the cloudwatch agent? maybe add this to your userdata: `sudo /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl -a fetch-config -m ec2 -c file:configuration-file-path -s`

Comment: This is a Windows instance and CloudWatch Agent registers itself as a System Service which starts on boot. But you might be right about running fetch-config through a user data script. I don't know if that's in addition to or instead of the system service. It's just so convoluted compared to if the system service just read the JSON directly. Or if the default were "use my instance id" rather than "use a stale instance id".

Comment: Are you using SSM to install the agent? if you look in amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl.ps1, there's a line calling `config-translator.exe` that does the json to toml conversion, you may have to force that to run and then restart the CWAgent service

Answer (score 2):

I believe that doing "amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl start" from your user-data is probably what they want you to do. They don't ever tell you anywhere that, not that I found, but that should create the TOML (if you make sure it doesn't already exist) and then start/restart the service. But "start" has a download part and I wasn't sure what to there given my JSON file is local.

So I did something different, but same idea:

1. Set the AmazonCloudWatchAgent service to manual start
2. Run the below batch file at boot with Task Scheduler

The below batch file will create the TOML then start the service:

```
SET CLOUD_WATCH="C:\Program Files\Amazon\AmazonCloudWatchAgent"
SET CLOUD_WATCH_DATA=C:\ProgramData\Amazon\AmazonCloudWatchAgent

SET JSON=%CLOUD_WATCH_DATA%\amazon-cloudwatch-agent.json
SET TOML=%CLOUD_WATCH_DATA%\amazon-cloudwatch-agent.toml
SET CONFIG=%CLOUD_WATCH_DATA%\common-config.toml

SET TRANSLATOR=%CLOUD_WATCH%\config-translator.exe

rem Translate JSON into TOML
%TRANSLATOR% --input %JSON% --output %TOML% --mode ec2 --config %CONFIG%

rem Start the service
sc start AmazonCloudWatchAgent
```

This seems to work for me. Also I make sure my AMI has empty log files, both the CloudWatch Agent's log and my own logs. So every instance starts fresh.

But I might switch to user-data "amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl start" at some point if I can make it work.